# SSRS Expression syntax for choosing a second field if the first one is null

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add an expression where one field (userdefined1) is selected unless it is null in which case a second field (accountname_calculated) is selected. They are both text fields. I've tried multiple permutations of the syntax below and am running into aggregate errors. Both Fields I want to select are in the same dataset (Dataset1).

=First(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!userdefined1.value,Fields!accountName_calculated.Value),"DataSet1"))
The value expression for the text box uses an aggregate expression without a scope

```
=iif(isNothing(Fields!userdefined1.Value), Fields!accountname_calculated.Value, Fields!userdefined1.Value)     the value expression for the text box refers directly to userdefined1 without specifying a dataset aggregate

=iif(isNothing(first(Fields!userdefined1.Value), Fields!accountname_calculated.Value, Fields!userdefined1.Value), "dataset1") the value expression for the text box refers directly to accountname_calculated without specifying a dataset aggregate
```

I tried various other combinations and got similar errors. Can some one please let me know how to correct this syntax. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a text box that's not part of a dataset which gives the first error. The method you are using will select the First of the values in the dataset. This should really only be used if your data only has one row or all the values for these fields are the same for each record.

That being said, I believe it would work if you wrapped the IIF in the FIRST with the scope:

```
=FIRST(IIF(isNothing(Fields!userdefined1.Value), Fields!accountname_calculated.Value, Fields!userdefined1.Value), "dataset1")
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Your syntax does work but for some reason it is causing errors rendering not only the textbox expression that was changed but all the other boxes as well. I added a picture. I'm not sure how changing 1 expression affected other text boxes. When I reverted the code, the boxes rendered as before. There were some error shown in SSMS and I still get them even after reverting the expression code so they might have always been there.  I removed the .data files. All of this data is coming from 1 row in an accounts table.

Comment: @DMAC - it sounds like it should work since there's only one row. Obviously it shouldn't affect the other text boxes. Maybe make a parameter that uses that logic for the default value?